# Why am I getting the error "button.addEventListener is not a function"

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, addeventlistener

Can somebody tell me why I am receiving the above error message with the following code?

It works fine on jsfiddle, though doesn't seem to want to run in the browser.

```js
var bladeRunnerButton = document.querySelector("ul.bladeRunner").innerHTML;
var bladeRunnerContent = document.querySelector("div.bladeRunner").innerHTML;

var detroitButton = document.querySelector("ul.detroit").innerHTML;
var detroitContent = document.querySelector("div.detroit").innerHTML;

var mammejongButton = document.querySelector("ul.mammejong").innerHTML;
var mammejongContent = document.querySelector("div.mammejong").innerHTML;

var buttonArray = [bladeRunnerButton, detroitButton, mammejongButton];
var articleArray = [bladeRunnerContent, detroitContent, mammejongContent];



function createfunc(i) {
    return function() { document.getElementById("fillPane").innerHTML = articleArray[i];};
}


for (let i=0; i < articleArray.length; i++) {
let button = buttonArray[i];
button.addEventListener("click", createfunc(i));
}
```

```css
#content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<li>
<ul class="bladeRunner">Blade Runner 2049</ul>
<ul class="detroit">Detroit</ul>
<ul class="mammejong">Mammejong</ul>
</li>

<div class="contentPanel bladeRunner">
</div>

<div class="contentPanel detroit">
</div>

<div class="contentPanel mammejong">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should target the [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) not the `innerHTML` to attach the event. So remove `innerHTML` from the following:

```
var bladeRunnerButton = document.querySelector("ul.bladeRunner");
var detroitButton = document.querySelector("ul.detroit");
var mammejongButton = document.querySelector("ul.mammejong");
```

Working Code Example with few modifications in the code:

```js
var bladeRunnerButton = document.querySelector("ul.bladeRunner");
var bladeRunnerContent = document.querySelector("div.bladeRunner").innerHTML;

var detroitButton = document.querySelector("ul.detroit");
var detroitContent = document.querySelector("div.detroit").innerHTML;

var mammejongButton = document.querySelector("ul.mammejong");
var mammejongContent = document.querySelector("div.mammejong").innerHTML;

var buttonArray = [bladeRunnerButton, detroitButton, mammejongButton];
var articleArray = [bladeRunnerContent, detroitContent, mammejongContent];

function createfunc(i) {
  document.getElementById("fillPane").innerHTML = articleArray[i];
}

for (let i=0; i < articleArray.length; i++) {
  let button = buttonArray[i];
  button.addEventListener("click", function(){createfunc(i)});
}
```

```css
.contentPanel {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <ul class="bladeRunner">Blade Runner 2049</ul>
  <ul class="detroit">Detroit</ul>
  <ul class="mammejong">Mammejong</ul>
</li>

<div class="contentPanel bladeRunner">Blade Runner</div>
<div class="contentPanel detroit">Detroit</div>
<div class="contentPanel mammejong">Mammejong</div>

<div id="fillPane"></div>
```